# Elementor add new custom responsive breakpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I'm making a little plugin that will add a new option for responsive. But I have no idea at the moment and I’ve been looking for hooks everywhere, but I feel like Elementor’s team has locked that option. Can someone help me where I could find a hook if it exists at all. So I want certain content to be displayed on a specific screen (which I would add using a code).
[image]

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-breakpoints-for-elementor/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a plugin. My idea is to make my own plugin and that’s why I’m looking for a hook to connect and make my own.